# How to bind top 20 records in Telerik Mvc Grid using Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, linq, telerik-mvc

I am  using  Telerik Grid in my ASP.NET MVC3 application to  display  my  records.

The  problem  is  that in my database I have millions of records. So I don't want to  bind all records  at single  time because  of performance issues. So I need a  logic so can I bind just 20  records  first. Remember my filter/sorting should work for whole DB not only for 20 records.

Actually my concern is performance because my query returning all millions of records, why 
should i return all millions of records when i need to display only 20 or may be 30 in a grid. So i want to save loading time which is unwanted

Thanks

Here is my Action

```
[GridAction]
    public ActionResult AjaxBibHierarchy()
    {
        return View(new GridModel(GetCommands()));

    }

    private IQueryable<BibViewModel> GetCommands()
    {
        var bib = (from a in db.Bibs
                   join inf in db.InfoTypes
                   on a.InfoTypeId equals inf.Id
                   where a.Status == "A"

                   select new BibViewModel
                   {
                       Title = db.BibContents.Where(x => x.TagNo == "245" && x.Sfld == "a").Select(y => y.NormValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Author = db.BibContents.Where(x => x.TagNo == "100" && x.Sfld == "a").Select(y => y.NormValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Id = a.Id,
                       Type = inf.Type,
                       InfoType = inf.Description,
                       Contents = "",
                       CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn

                   });
        return bib;

    }
```

View

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Vibrant.Areas.Cataloging.Models.BibViewModel>()
                            .Name("Bib")
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()

        )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Width(300).Title("Title");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Author).Width(120).Title("Author");
        columns.Bound(o => o.InfoType).Width(120).Title("InfoType");
        columns.Bound(o => o.CatalogueDate).Width(120).Title("Cat.Date").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}");
        columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedOn).Width(120).Title("Created On").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}");

    })
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()

                 .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server().Select("BibIndex", "Bib"))
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxBibHierarchy", "Bib").Enabled(true))
                                       .Scrollable(x => x.Height("auto"))
                                                      .Sortable(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Add(z => z.CreatedOn).Descending()))
          .Pageable(page =>
          {
              page.PageSize(10);
          })
    )
```

Comment: How about Take(20) Extionssion Method.

Comment: Why you don't use .Take(20)?

Comment: If i  use take()  command  my  grid  filtering  filtered  from  20  records  only.  it  should  search   for  all  records.?

Comment: Take a look http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-paging.html

Answer (score 0):

here is an simple example.

import **System.Linq** namespace

```
 var procs = (from p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
                     where p.ProcessName.StartsWith("s") // filter if needed. 
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = p.ProcessName,
                         Title = p.MainWindowTitle
                     }).Take(20).ToList(); ;
```

Comment: If i use take() command my grid filtering filtered from 20 records only. it should search for all records.?

Comment: there  are  lot  of  condition  in  telerik filtering  ..  so  it  means  for  each  filter  event  i  should  write a query  to  fetch  data

Answer (score 0):

As I Undrestood , you want to take 20 records after all telerik filters applied. A simple way (indeed work around) is to set the page size to 20 and then disable the footer :

```
        .Pageable(page =>
    {
        page.PageSize(20);
    }).Footer(false)
```

or If you don't want to disable the footer, simply remove the paging bar with dist simple trick :

```
$('.t-pager','#YourGridId').remove();
```

**EDIT :**

Your  view model can be started like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<CommandGridViewModel>
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("GridCommands")
        .DataKeys(keys =>
        {
            keys.Add(c => c.Id);
        })
        .Pageable(page =>
        {
            page.PageSize(10);
        })

     ...

    .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
    {
        dataBinding.Server()
            .Select("Index", "Commands");

        dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("AjaxIndex", "Commands").Enabled(true);
    })
```

and your ajaxIndex action can be like this :

```
[GridAction]
public ViewResult AjaxIndex()
{
   return View(new GridModel(GetCommands()));
}
private IQueryable<CommandGridViewModel> GetCommands()
{
   return from r in contenxt.Commands
          select new { r.Id , r.Name , r.Status , r.Type };

}
```

Comment: ok  but  when  i  filtered ...i  can't   filter  whole  from  db  .  my  filter  command  running  for  just  20  records  only

Comment: @KapsHasija NO! the above solution fetches 20 records after all filtering and sorting have been done. Note that you should not change your binding query by appending ".take(20)"  to them. I used it in lots of the cases I have

Comment: i  think  you  didn't  understand  my  requirement, actually  my concern is  performance bcoj  my  query  returning  all  millions  of  records,  why  should  i  return  all  millions ofrecords  when  i  need  to  display  only  20 or  may  be 30  in  a grid.  So  i  want  to  save  loading  time  which  is  unwanted.

Comment: @KapsHasija Yes! Telerik do it for you seamlessly! you can monitor your SQL database by SQL Profiler to see it just fetches 20 records in each call! but note that, you should pass an IQueryable to your GridModel. Indeed you should avoid .ToList() . Check it and enjoy it :)

Comment: can  give  any  example  to  to  pass  iqueryable data to  gridmodel

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud You  can  see  i  have applied  your   code,But  still  its  returning  all  records  from  my  db  it  should  return  only 10 records  as  per  given  my  Pagesize  in  telerik grid.
you can see  this  link [Return More then 10 records](http://postimg.org/image/lezsjru7f/)

Comment: @KapsHasija you check it in debug mode! when you mouse "watch" it , it runs the query but keep in mind that telerik complete your query (adding filtering,ordering,paging,grouping,...) in your view and then calls "ToList". As I told you before monitor your database with SQL Profiler to see what happends in run-time.

Comment: First  Sorry  for  late reply, As per my  understanding acc. to you telerik  fetch  only 20  records  on  view at a time. so  ok fine,  but the  again   main problem  is that my   query  returning  all records so  its  taking  so  long  for  me.  i   just  want  to  return  only 20 records  from  controler  it self.

Comment: @KapsHasija your query never runs alone! IT IS exactly writing your SQL Query but not running it! It runs ONLY after Telerik COMPLETEs your query. I think you should read a little more about EF/Linq :)